# PHP produces a blank webpage

Tags: php, html

When ever I use this piece of PHP, it makes the webpage blank (white) and does not show anything. Here is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pwrd = $_POST['pwrd'];
//include database connection
include('../includes/db_connect.php');
if(empty($user) || empty($pwrd)){
    echo 'Missing information';
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<form action="Login.php" mthod="post">
    <p>
    <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="username" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="pwrd" />    
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="logIn" />
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After testing different pieces of the PHP code, I have noticed only this code make the page blank

```
if(empty($user) || empty($pwrd)){
    echo 'Missing information';
}
?>
```

Is this possibly something to do with Apache, or is there something wrong with my PHP?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`  at the top.  If that doesn't work, look at your httpd log.

Comment: put `<? }?>` after `</html>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are following problem:-

1. your first if bracket is not closed. So closed it.
2. your form method is not correct. Spelling mistake:-

So the correct code is here :-

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pwrd = $_POST['pwrd'];
    //include database connection
    include('../includes/db_connect.php');
    if(empty($user) || empty($pwrd)){
        echo 'Missing information';
    }
}// missing
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<form action="Login.php" method="post"> // method is written mthod
    <p>
    <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="username" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="pwrd" />    
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="logIn" />
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:- before submit :- http://prntscr.com/74xhb7
After submit :-  http://prntscr.com/74xhmm

Note:- the bracket that i said you to close you can close it based on your convinence. Thanks.

Also don't panic with error you seen in second screenshot. It's because i am not having included files at my end.